# How can i add a £ symbol before echoing price

Tags: php, mysql, symbols

I am trying to echo my price field but I need a £ symbol before it, I have tried adding it to this line of code but i keep getting errors, help please!

```
  echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
```

Comment: `echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "£</td>";`

Comment: `echo "<td>£ " . $row['price'] . "</td>";`

Comment: May I ask what you have already tried, and what error you're getting ?

Comment: ups, I've read "after" ...

Comment: `echo "<td>&pound;". $row['price'] . "</td>";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this"

```
echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "£</td>";
```

Or instead of £ with HTML output you can always write

```
&pound;
```

like this:

```
echo "<td>&pound;". $row['price'] . "</td>";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "<td> £" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
```

You could add as well to get a standard amount with a comma seperating thousands

```
  "<td> £" . number_format( $row['price']) . "</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<td> &pound;" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
```